# Android - how to make RotateAnimation more smooth and "physical"?

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-sensors

I'm implementing a kind of a "compass arrow" that follows destination depending on physical orientation of the device using magnetic field sensor. Suddenly I faced with a little problem.

Obtaining bearing and azimuth is OK, but performing a realistic animation turned into a really hard task. I tried to use different interpolators to make animation more "physical" (i. e. as in real compass, which arrow oscillate after hairpin rotation, accelerate and decelerate during movement etc).

Now I'm using `interpolator.accelerate_decelerate` and everything is quite good until updates start arriving quickly. That makes animations overlap each other and the arrow becomes twitchy and nervous. I want to avoid this. I tried to implement a queue to make every next animation wait until previous ends, or drop updates that come very quickly. That made animation look smooth, but arrow's behavior turned into absolutely illogical.

**So I have 2 questions:**

1) is there some way to *make animated transitions more smooth in the cases when animations overlap each other*?

2) is there a way to *stop animation that is currently processing and get intermediate position of an object?*

My code is below. An `UpdateRotation()` method handles orientation and bearing updates and executes animation of external `viewArrow` view.

```
public class DirectionArrow {

// View that represents the arrow
final View viewArrow;

// speed of rotation of the arrow, degrees/sec
final double rotationSpeed;

// current values of bearing and azimuth
float bearingCurrent = 0;
float azimuthCurrent = 0;


/*******************************************************************************/

/**
 * Basic constructor
 * 
 * @param   view            View representing an arrow that should be rotated
 * @param   rotationSpeed   Speed of rotation in deg/sec. Recommended from 50 (slow) to 500 (fast)
 */
public DirectionArrow(View view, double rotationSpeed) {
    this.viewArrow = view;
    this.rotationSpeed = rotationSpeed;
}

/**
 * Extended constructor
 * 
 * @param   viewArrow       View representing an arrow that should be rotated
 * @param   rotationSpeed   Speed of rotation in deg/sec. Recommended from 50 (slow) to 500 (fast)
 * @param   bearing         Initial bearing 
 * @param   azimuth         Initial azimuth
 */
public DirectionArrow(View viewArrow, double rotationSpeed, float bearing, float azimuth){
    this.viewArrow = viewArrow;
    this.rotationSpeed = rotationSpeed;
    UpdateRotation(bearing, azimuth);
}

/**
 * Invoke this to update orientation and animate the arrow
 * 
 * @param   bearingNew  New bearing value, set >180 or <-180 if you don't need to update it 
 * @param   azimuthNew  New azimuth value, set >360 or <0 if you don't need to update it
 */
public void UpdateRotation(float bearingNew, float azimuthNew){

    // look if any parameter shouldn't be updated
    if (bearingNew < -180 || bearingNew > 180){
        bearingNew = bearingCurrent;
    }
    if (azimuthNew < 0 || azimuthNew > 360){
        azimuthNew = azimuthCurrent;
    }

    // log
    Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "compass", "Setting rotation: B=" + bearingNew + " A=" + azimuthNew);

    // calculate rotation value
    float rotationFrom = bearingCurrent - azimuthCurrent;
    float rotationTo = bearingNew - azimuthNew;

    // correct rotation angles
    if (rotationFrom < -180) {
        rotationFrom += 360;
    }
    while (rotationTo - rotationFrom < -180) {
        rotationTo += 360;
    }
    while (rotationTo - rotationFrom > 180) {
        rotationTo -= 360;
    }

    // log again
    Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "compass", "Start Rotation to " + rotationTo);

    // create an animation object
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(rotationFrom, rotationTo, 
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5);

    // set up an interpolator
    rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(viewArrow.getContext(), interpolator.accelerate_decelerate);

    // force view to remember its position after animation
    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    // set duration depending on speed
    rotateAnimation.setDuration((long) (Math.abs(rotationFrom - rotationTo) / rotationSpeed * 1000));

    // start animation
    viewArrow.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);

    // update cureent rotation
    bearingCurrent = bearingNew;
    azimuthCurrent = azimuthNew;
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is my custom ImageDraw class where I implemted physical behavior of the pointing arrow based on equation of circular motion of dipole in magnetic field.

It don't uses any animators nor interpolators--on every iteration angular position is recalculated based on physical parameters. These parameters can be widely adjusted via `setPhysical` method. For example, to make rotations more smooth and slow, increase `alpha` (damping coefficient), to make arrow more responsitive, increase `mB` (coefficient of magnetic field), to make arrow oscillate on rotations, increase `inertiaMoment`.

Animation and redraw is performed implicitly by invoke of `invalidate()` on every iteration. There is no need to handle it explicitly.

To update the angle at which the arrow should rotate, just call `rotationUpdate` (by user's choice or using device orientation sensor callback).

```
/**
 * Class CompassView extends Android ImageView to perform cool, real-life animation of objects
 * such compass needle in magnetic field. Rotation is performed relative to the center of image.
 * 
 * It uses angular motion equation of magnetic dipole in magnetic field to implement such animation.
 * To vary behaviour (damping, oscillation, responsiveness and so on) set various physical properties.
 * 
 * Use `setPhysical()` to vary physical properties.
 * Use `rotationUpdate()` to change angle of "magnetic field" at which image should rotate.
 *
 */

public class CompassView extends ImageView {

static final public float TIME_DELTA_THRESHOLD = 0.25f; // maximum time difference between iterations, s 
static final public float ANGLE_DELTA_THRESHOLD = 0.1f; // minimum rotation change to be redrawn, deg

static final public float INERTIA_MOMENT_DEFAULT = 0.1f;    // default physical properties
static final public float ALPHA_DEFAULT = 10;
static final public float MB_DEFAULT = 1000;

long time1, time2;              // timestamps of previous iterations--used in numerical integration
float angle1, angle2, angle0;   // angles of previous iterations
float angleLastDrawn;           // last drawn anglular position
boolean animationOn = false;    // if animation should be performed

float inertiaMoment = INERTIA_MOMENT_DEFAULT;   // moment of inertia
float alpha = ALPHA_DEFAULT;    // damping coefficient
float mB = MB_DEFAULT;  // magnetic field coefficient

/**
 * Constructor inherited from ImageView
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public CompassView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

/**
 * Constructor inherited from ImageView
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 */
public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

/**
 * Constructor inherited from ImageView
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyle
 */
public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * onDraw override.
 * If animation is "on", view is invalidated after each redraw, 
 * to perform recalculation on every loop of UI redraw
 */
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    if (animationOn){
        if (angleRecalculate(new Date().getTime())){
            this.setRotation(angle1);
        }
    } else {
        this.setRotation(angle1);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (animationOn){
        this.invalidate();
    }
}

/**
 * Use this to set physical properties. 
 * Negative values will be replaced by default values
 * 
 * @param inertiaMoment Moment of inertia (default 0.1)
 * @param alpha             Damping coefficient (default 10)
 * @param mB                Magnetic field coefficient (default 1000)
 */
public void setPhysical(float inertiaMoment, float alpha, float mB){
    this.inertiaMoment = inertiaMoment >= 0 ? inertiaMoment : this.INERTIA_MOMENT_DEFAULT;
    this.alpha = alpha >= 0 ? alpha : ALPHA_DEFAULT;
    this.mB = mB >= 0 ? mB : MB_DEFAULT;
}


/**
 * Use this to set new "magnetic field" angle at which image should rotate
 * 
 * @param   angleNew    new magnetic field angle, deg., relative to vertical axis.
 * @param   animate     true, if image shoud rotate using animation, false to set new rotation instantly
 */
public void rotationUpdate(final float angleNew, final boolean animate){
    if (animate){
        if (Math.abs(angle0 - angleNew) > ANGLE_DELTA_THRESHOLD){
            angle0 = angleNew;
            this.invalidate();
        }
        animationOn = true;
    } else {
        angle1 = angleNew;
        angle2 = angleNew;
        angle0 = angleNew;
        angleLastDrawn = angleNew;
        this.invalidate();
        animationOn = false;
    }
}

/**
 * Recalculate angles using equation of dipole circular motion
 * 
 * @param   timeNew     timestamp of method invoke
 * @return              if there is a need to redraw rotation
 */
protected boolean angleRecalculate(final long timeNew){

    // recalculate angle using simple numerical integration of motion equation
    float deltaT1 = (timeNew - time1)/1000f;
    if (deltaT1 > TIME_DELTA_THRESHOLD){
        deltaT1 = TIME_DELTA_THRESHOLD;
        time1 = timeNew + Math.round(TIME_DELTA_THRESHOLD * 1000);
    }
    float deltaT2 = (time1 - time2)/1000f;
    if (deltaT2 > TIME_DELTA_THRESHOLD){
        deltaT2 = TIME_DELTA_THRESHOLD;
    }

    // circular acceleration coefficient
    float koefI = inertiaMoment / deltaT1 / deltaT2;

    // circular velocity coefficient
    float koefAlpha = alpha / deltaT1;

    // angular momentum coefficient
    float koefk = mB * (float)(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle0))*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle1)) - 
                             (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle1))*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle0))));

    float angleNew = ( koefI*(angle1 * 2f - angle2) + koefAlpha*angle1 + koefk) / (koefI + koefAlpha);

    // reassign previous iteration variables
    angle2 = angle1;
    angle1 = angleNew;
    time2 = time1;
    time1 = timeNew;

    // if angles changed less then threshold, return false - no need to redraw the view
    if (Math.abs(angleLastDrawn - angle1) < ANGLE_DELTA_THRESHOLD){
        return false;
    } else {
        angleLastDrawn = angle1;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply amazing... Thank you so much for sharing this! Just what I needed and couldn't accomplish myself.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this!

Comment: Yes, this is excelent.

Answer (score 1):

Are you filtering your sensor data? The Magnetometer is a pain low pass filtering isn't really enough. You could use [weighted-smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611599/help-smoothing-data-from-a-sensor) or maybe rounding data would be helpful:
Math.round( xyz * 10) / 10; ?
You could also reduce the frequency at which you get sensor updates. That might help.

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mMagnetometer, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to replace animation by frame-by-frame rotation using smoothing function. That's a good approach.

Comment: Any luck? I'm curious to see your solution. :D

Comment: I think I will try to implement exponential smoothing as first approach and dumped oscillator equation as second to see what looks nicer and more realistic. I still haven't found any way to implement it using Android animations, and, I beware, there is no way to.

Comment: I think I approach it a different way. I try to smooth the data and let the animation do what it does. Can't you just define a custom View and move it with sensor data?

Comment: I have 2 angles in my app, ok, let's consider that `azimuth` will change according to sensor data and repeating its physics will move quite smoothly. So what to do with `bearing` angle that can change intermittently due to user's choice. That's why I cannot avoid overlapping animations.

Comment: If you want some reference, I can send you a View I have.

Comment: no problem, I found a nice image of compass needle and make experiments with this ImageView =)

Comment: I did implemented custom `ImageView` using angular motion equation and view's `invalidate` method to iterate animation.

Answer (score 1):

Espessially for gilonm, nice implementation of fixed size queue and getting its mean value:

```
float queue[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {0};
int queueFront = queue.length - 1 // position of front element
float meanValue = 0; // calculated mean value

float pushNewAndGetMean(float newValue){
   // recalculate mean value
   meanValue = meanValue + (newValue - queue[queueFront]) / queue.length;
   // overwrite value in front pointer position
   queue[queueFront] = newValue;
   // shift front pointer 1 step right or to '0' if end of array reached
   queueStart = (queueFront + 1) % array.length;

   return  meanValue
};
```

Here, not dependent on array length, you make just 2 reassignments of variables (instead of N) and use only 3 elements in mean calculation (instead of N). This makes algorithm O(1) complexity instead of O(N).

Comment: Thanks! I will try to implement this.. thanks for your kind help!

Comment: BTW, if I use the method I proposed - the more elements in the array - the more smoothing I get (and less accurate). Is there a way to change the ratio of smoothing-accuracy using your method?

Comment: more smooth doesn't mean less accurate. Due to central limit theorem, accuracy increases when number of measurements is increased. By the way it works only in situations when compass is in stable position. When moving, every kind of interpolation will result time lag--because you cannot predict how it will be moved at the next moment

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is where you get your data from the sensors - you can just use and array to do an average of say last 5 readings - that should smooth things down.

something like this:

Declare an array `private float azimArray[] = {0,0,0,0,0};`

Now where you get sensor data, use:

`azimArray[0] = azimArray[1];
azimArray[1] = azimArray[2];
azimArray[2] = azimArray[3];
azimArray[3] = azimArray[4];
azimArray[4] = event.values[0];  //get actual sensor data into last array cell
currentAzimuth = Math.round(azimArray[0]+azimArray[1]+azimArray[2]+azimArray[3]+azimArray[4]/5);`

Now currentAzimuth holds the rounded average of last 5 readings, which should smooth things down for you.

Hope this helped!

Comment: thanx, but my question is not about obtaining data from the sensor, it is about possibility of smoothing animations when one goes after other and overlap it. And, sorry, your method of updating and array and its mean value is incorrect and inefficient -- you do it in O(n) time when it can be easily done in O(1) time

Comment: Hi, I understand that it is the smoothing you are looking for. What I have written to you worked actually quite good for me in smoothing the compass animation down. I used an Array[7], the animation duration was set to 500ms, and sensor updates to UI. 

1) I would be grateful if you could explain the last part of your comment about it being inefficiant

2) have you found any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: yes I succeeded with my problem. See both my answers here for my solution and proper algorithm for calculating mean value of fixed size queue.